# Node.js, express, jade, highcharts and 2D array

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, highcharts, pug

Disclaimer, I'm pretty new to javascript/node.js/express/jade/highcharts etc...

To my problem
I have a template that receives few parameters which i Pre-process in my router code.
The parameters are chunked into 1 object and represent the high chart graph both meta-data and series data.

I have a problem when I'm trying to pass a 2D array to my jade template which represents my data series, but in the chrome dev tools it looks like a normal array.
My Highcharts code is based on: [Highcharts column graph](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-rotated-labels/)

Here's my code:

**delivered.js**

```
var callback = function process_results(result){
    var res = new Object()
    res.title = "Delivery Count"
    res.yAxisTitle = 'Delivered'
    res.seriesName = "Delivered per month"
    res.seriesData = []
    for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
        //process the query results
        row = result.rows[i]
        date = "\'" + row.month_delivered + '/' + row.year_delivered + "\'"
        count = row.count
        res.seriesData.push([date,count])
    };
    console.log(res)
    response.render('column-graph', res)
}
```

**column-graph.jade**

```
html
    head
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
        script(type='text/javascript', src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js")
        script(type='text/javascript', src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js")
        script(type='text/javascript', src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js")
        title Delivered Leads
   body
    div#container(style="min-width: 500px; height: 500px; margin: 0 auto")
    script.
        $(function () {
            $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: "#{title}"
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: Internal DB'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'category',          
            labels: {
                rotation: -45,
                style: {
                    fontSize: '13px',
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                    }
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: "#{yAxisTitle}"
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
                name: '#{seriesName}',
                data: [#{seriesData}],
                dataGrouping: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    rotation: -90,
                    color: '#FFFFFF',
                    align: 'right',
                        x: 4,
                        y: 10,
                        style: {
                            fontSize: '13px',
                            fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif',
                            textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
                        }
                    }
                }]
            });
        });
```

the #{seriesData} param is res.seriesData which supposed to be a 2D array.
in the delivered.js, I have a console.log(res) that shows this:

```
{ title: 'Delivery Count',
  yAxisTitle: 'Delivered',
  seriesName: 'Delivered per month',
  seriesData:
   [ [ '\'7/2014\'', '3000' ],
     [ '\'6/2014\'', '5163' ],
     [ '\'5/2014\'', '23882' ],
     [ '\'4/2014\'', '26471' ],
     [ '\'3/2014\'', '82172' ],
     [ '\'2/2014\'', '31283' ],
     [ '\'1/2014\'', '637400' ],
     [ '\'12/2013\'', '86420' ],
     [ '\'11/2013\'', '119150' ],
     [ '\'10/2013\'', '49093' ] ] }
```

But when I look at it in the browser, I get this:

```
  series: [{
    name: 'Delivered per month',
    data: ['7/2014',3000,'6/2014',5163,'5/2014',23882,'4/2014',26471,'3/2014',82172,'2/2014',31283,'1/2014',637400,'12/2013',86420,'11/2013',119150,'10/2013',49093],
    dataGrouping: {
        enabled: true
    },
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        rotation: -90,
        color: '#FFFFFF',
        align: 'right',
        x: 4,
        y: 10,
        style: {
            fontSize: '13px',
            fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif',
            textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
           }
       }
   }]
});
```

Sorry for the long question,
and thanks in advance!!

Comment: Your each item should be ['7/2014', 3000] , where 3000 is number, not string. Data should be array of numbers (only y value) or array of arrays (pair: category, value). The dataGrouping is available only in the highstock, when you use number/datetime type of xAxis not categories.

Answer (score 3):

Eventually, I did something else.
Instead of preprocessing the array in delivered.js,
I passed the array as it is to the jade template and did the following:

```
html
  head
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    script(type='text/javascript', src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js")
    script(type='text/javascript', src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js")
    script(type='text/javascript', src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js")
    title Delivered Leads      
  body
    div#container(style="min-width: 500px; height: 500px; margin: 0 auto")
    script.
        var arrToMultiArr = function(arr){
        var result = new Array()
        for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i+=2){
          var date = arr[i]
          var count = arr[i + 1]
          result.push([date, count])
        }
        return result
    };
    var mySeries = arrToMultiArr([#{seriesData}])

    $(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: "#{title}"
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: Internal DB'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'category',          
            labels: {
                rotation: -45,
                style: {
                    fontSize: '13px',
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                }
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: "#{yAxisTitle}"
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: '#{seriesName}',
            data: mySeries,
            dataGrouping: {
                enabled: true
            },
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                rotation: -90,
                color: '#FFFFFF',
                align: 'right',
                x: 4,
                y: 10,
                style: {
                    fontSize: '11px',
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif',
                    textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
                }
            }
        }]
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
data: [#{seriesData}],
```

to:

```
data: #{seriesData},
```

Comment: Hi,
This does't seem to help:
This is how it looks like
    series: [{
        name: 'Delivered per month',
        data: '7/2014',3000,'6/2014',5163,'5/2014',23882,'4/2014',26471,'3/2014',82172,'2/2014',31283,'1/2014',637400,'12/2013',86420,'11/2013',119150,'10/2013',49093,
...

It doesn't get rendered.